# Display PHP Opcode without execution

Tags: php, opcode

To display the opcode for a specific file (example.php), there are two extensions [VLD](https://github.com/derickr/vld) and [Zend Opchache](https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php).

VLD has the property to generate the opcode without executing the file, when we choose vld.execute=0.

```
php -d vld.active=1 -d vld.execure=0 example.php
```

My question: Can I generate the opcode by using Zend Opcache but without executing the file? And what I have to change in the configuration file to have this option?

```
php -d opcache.opt_debug_level=0x10000 example.php
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by invoking [`opcache_compile_file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-compile-file.php) and passing it the file path.

You can do this from CLI like so:

```
php -d opcache.opt_debug_level=0x10000 -r 'opcache_compile_file("example.php");'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one issue that in this case the opcode will be generated without the included and required files. So if I have include("library1.php") inside example.php. It will print the opcodes only for example.php. While in the normal case it will print the opcodes for both of the files. Do you know if there is another feature allow to me to do that. Thanks :))

Comment: Not natively in the opcache extension, no.

It wouldn't be difficult to use a library like [`nikic/php-parser`](https://github.com/nikic/php-parser) to parse each file you send to opcache for `include`, `include_once`, `require`, and/or `require_once` statements to know what other files you need to send to opcache, though.